# I'm here to run the official Go-Ethereum repo. How can i do that?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, golang, hardforks, blockchain-fork

I want to run  [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) in my own PC. Is there any instruction about this? How they deployed it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make project from resource

- install go
- you need clone go-ethereum
- make it

More details in official documentations: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth#windows

If you are needed only executable client go to https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/